# Entity Framework 4, POCO: Clearer way to constrain an EF POCO other than where E : class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, poco, constraints

Morshed Anwar's article ["Implementing Repository Pattern with Entity Framework"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/implrepositorypatternef.aspx) 
starts off with this at the top of his repository:

```
public class Repository<E, C> : IRepository<E, C>, IDisposable
    where E : EntityObject
    where C : ObjectContext
{ ... }
```

Say you want to use ASP.NET POCO Entity Generator, you could change `EntityObject` to `class`.  However, in order to get all the properties of the EntityObject, you would need to use reflection to determine that the class does in fact have all the properties and methods of an EntityObject.

Is there a better constraint other than `class` we could substitute for `EntityObject` using  [ASP.NET POCO Entity Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fe568da5-aa1a-4178-a2a5-48813c707a7f) to expose the `EntityObject` properties and methods normally available using `where E : EntityObject`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, that Generic Repository implementation is ugly (CodeProject, in general, has been a disappointing source for good examples in my opinion). There's no two ways around it.

When using POCO Objects, there's really no reason to need to reflect. Take advantage of the `EntityContext.CreateObjectSet<T>` method and let Entity Framework worry about the details.

If you want to take a look at a much cleaner Generic Repository implementation, check out:

[Elegant Code >> Entity Framework POCO (EF4): Generic Repository and Unit of Work](http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/)

Comment: Good advice.  So the answer is either "don't do it that way at all" or "class is the only constraint you can use on a POCO".

Answer (score 1):

I think you mis-understand the concept of "POCO"; POCO stands for Plain Old CLR Object.  So your POCO objects don't have any "normal properties and methods".  They have only the properties and methods that you give to them, that's the whole point.

Now you could customize your POCO T4 templates and make all of your POCO classes derive from a specific base class, or implement a specific interface if you want.  I often have a pattern where all my classes have a `public Guid Id` property, and so I have a base class which includes this property (and maybe some auditing dates).  I then modify the templates to derive my POCO classes from this base class and exclude the `Id` property from being generated.  Given this kind of scenario, I could use by base class as a restriction in the `where` constraint.

Comment: In the context, the ASP.NET POCO Entity Generator generates classes that have virtual modifiers.  POCOs would be plain but the derived classes would have overridden EF methods and properties.  So, we would have to question whether overriding a POCO in a derived class fits with the POCO lifestyle.  I am not qualified enough to answer that question.

Comment: The EF does not add anything to your POCO classes, the POCO templates use `virtual` members to support creating proxy classes which can be used for change tracking and/or lazy loading.  But you _never_ see these proxies in your code, and therefore your POCO classes have no special methods or properties other than those that you give to them.  Maybe you understand that point, but based on your question it sounds like you think there are other properties and/or methods that the EF is "adding to" your POCO classes.

Comment: Well, I would like to determine the primary key of the Entity so I could order it before I do a .Skip and .Take.  Inside the Repository, I can access the underlying methods of the EF using the POCOs by casting them (POCOs generated by the ASP.NET POCO Entity Generator).

Comment: I understand, that is why I use the method that I described.  I _know_ that my entities will always have these certain properties (namely the `Id` property), that way I can do exactly the kinds of things that you're asking about.  I can constrain my generic's to always be of type `MyEntityBase` and therefore I will always have access to the `Id` property.